# Opening CSS popup window via C# code behind

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

I have a HTML code as following:

```
     <a id="PopUp" runat="server" href="#openModal">Open me</a> 
// this is a way to open the pop up window via HTML

                <div id="openModal" runat="server" class="modalDialog">
        <div>
            <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
            <h2 style="text-align:center">Error</h2>
            <p style="text-align:center"> Please select the product first!</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

As you can see, I'm setting my href link to #openModal so that I can open the pop up window which is designed in CSS...  My question is now, is there any way that I do this dynamically in C# from code behind?

I've tried the following code:

```
    if(something..)
    {
    do something...
    }
    else
    {
    // now we need to open the pop up message if the if didn't pass first term...
    // I tried the following:                   
openModal.Attributes.CssStyle.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Display, "block");
    // or
    PopUp.Href="#openModal";
    }
```

But none of these actually worked, can someone help me out with this, how can I do this from code behind? Thanks!

P.S. The code is set to trigger when the user clicks the button inside the listview (normal asp.net button)...

Edit: ( **Roberth**, did you mean like this??):

```
  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                        <Triggers>
                            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger controlid="DropDownList1" eventname="SelectedIndexChanged" />
                             <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger controlid="Button1" eventname="Click" />
                        </Triggers>
                        <ContentTemplate>
                           <asp:DropDownList  ID="DropDownList1" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList> 
                          <cc1:ModalPopupExtender runat="server" ID="kontroller" PopupControlID="popUpController" TargetControlID="PopUp">

                          </cc1:ModalPopupExtender>
                                                     <asp:Button ID="PopUp" runat="server" CommandName="AddToCart"  CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ProductID")%>' Text="Add to cart" />

                               </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Code behind:

```
            ModalPopupExtender mpe = e.Item.FindControl("kontroller") as ModalPopupExtender;
            mpe.Show();
            return;
```

But nothing happens...

Comment: Yes , you are on the right track. But you don't have to 'find' the control, you should be able to access it with its ID. And why is there <cc1: in the declaration? I think the AjaxControlToolkit is not registered. Did you drag 'n drop the control in the grapical editor? It shoudl say:  <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID='xxx' runat="server", etc..

Comment: You could first try it without UpdatePanel, like this: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/215040/ModalPopupExtender-from-Server-Side-Code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot start some action in the browser from code-behind the way you could in javascript. You can only update the client during the postback's reponse.

To update the client without refreshing the whole page, you should use a UpdatePanel. To start a PopUp you can use ModalPopupExtender (part of AjaxControlToolkit, in NuGet).

So, the whole procedure is as follows:

1. Users does something that triggers a postback
2. Code-behind opens a Modal Dialog using some code like: **Demo_ModalPopupExtender.Show();**. You can also update it's title, message or any other control in it.
3. The Modal Dialog html-code in the browser is updated because it's inside a Update-Panel.
4. The dialog opens.

Here is an example: You can set the text of the dialog with **LabelMsgBox.Text =**

```
<asp:Button ID="HiddenButtonPopUpMsgBox" runat="server" Style="display: none" />
    <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="MsgBoxModalPopupExtender" runat="server" DropShadow="True"
        PopupDragHandleControlID="DragPanelMsgBox" BackgroundCssClass="popUpbackground"
        CancelControlID="ButtonMsgBoxClose" PopupControlID="PanelMsgBox" TargetControlID="HiddenButtonPopUpMsgBox">
    </ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>
    <asp:Panel ID="PanelMsgBox" runat="server" CssClass="popUpPanel" Style="display: none"
        DefaultButton="ButtonMsgBoxClose">
        <asp:Panel ID="DragPanelMsgBox" runat="server">
            <div class="popUpDragPanel">
            </div>
        </asp:Panel>
        <fieldset>
            <legend class="legendlist">Message</legend>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelMsgBox" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:Panel ID="PanelMsgScroll" runat="server" CssClass="PopUpPanelMsgPanel">
                        <asp:Label ID="LabelMsgBox" runat="server" Text="-" CssClass="MsgBoxLabel"></asp:Label>
                    </asp:Panel>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
            <div align="center">
                <asp:Button ID="ButtonMsgBoxClose" runat="server" Text="OK"
                    CssClass="button" />
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </asp:Panel>
```

You can open it with this:

```
public static void MsgBox(string title, Page page)
        {
            AjaxControlToolkit.ModalPopupExtender ModalPopupExtender =
                page.FindControl("ctl00$MainContent$MsgBoxModalPopupExtender") as AjaxControlToolkit.ModalPopupExtender;
            System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label Label =
                page.FindControl("ctl00$MainContent$LabelMsgBox") as System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label;

            string message = "<b>" + title + "</b>";

            Label.Text = message;

            UpdatePanel UpdatePanel = page.FindControl("ctl00$MainContent$UpdatePanelMsgBox") as UpdatePanel;            
            UpdatePanel.Update();
            ModalPopupExtender.Show();                

        }
```

Comment: Please check my updated answer, was that what you ment?